# Import Error when using VSCode with conda interpreter but not when importing in Conda

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, anaconda, python-import

I'm trying to run a Python program in VSCode and it always stops in the first line

`from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import WhiteKernel, RationalQuadratic, RBF, Matern, ExpSineSquared`

The error it gives me is pretty big, I'll paste it at the end.

However, when when I open python in my conda terminal, I can import with no issues at all. Since I'm using the conda interpreter in VSCode, I don't understand what the issue is.

My Python version is 3.7.6, numpy 1.19.1, scipy 1.5.2, sklearn 0.23.2 and am working with Windows 10. I have already tried what the webpage mentioned suggested. And on the bottom left of VSCode it says that the interpreter is Python 3.7.6 64-bit ('base':conda).

Just tried, and I can't import numpy either, but can in conda with no problems. The python versions are the same. EDIT: The error message here asks me to be sure that the Numpy version is 1.18.1, instead of 1.19.1.

**Exception has occurred: ImportError**

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

```
https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
```

Please note and check the following:

- The Python version is: Python3.7 from "C:\Users\jdion\anaconda3\python.exe"
- The NumPy version is: "1.19.1"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
File "C:\Users\jdion\OneDrive\Ambiente de Trabalho\Tese\Code\The Sea Exploration Problem _aux.py", line 13, in 
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import WhiteKernel, RationalQuadratic, RBF, Matern, ExpSineSquared

Comment: are u using jupyter notebook extension by any chance?

Comment: @YehdhihANNA, no, I'm not using it

Comment: so you are trying to execute the script in vscode terminal?

Comment: @YehdhihANNA, I'm not familiar with VSCode, but I'm running the script from inside it, just pressing F5

Comment: @J. Dionisio How did you install the "sklearn" module? Usually, DLL loading errors are caused by not entering the environment, so it is recommended that you try other VSCode terminals. (Ctrl+Shift+` , "Terminal:Select Default shell" , select "Command Prompt")

Comment: @JillCheng, thanks to your comment, I realized that I was installing and removing the packages in conda, but outside of VSCode, I didn't know that was a problem. I uninstalled conda and all python versions I had, and when I reinstalled python 3.7.9 the error didn't show up anymore. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled both conda and all my Python versions and when I reinstalled Python 3.7.9 and selected it as the interpreter in VSCode there were no more issues. I think the problem was having too many Python versions, anaconda, pip, and I was probably installing and removing things in the wrong places.